# How can an end-user email me their iOS app database?

Tags: ios, backup, itunes

I'm an iOS developer, and a user is reporting a strange problem that I'm not able to resolve without access to their SQLite app database.

However, as the app currently exists, I don't have iTunes File Sharing turned on, so there's no really easy way for the user to get the database off the phone.

How can I have her retrieve the database and send it to us? Is there any way to retrieve a single file from a specific app out of iTunes backup?